# Java Slack Bot: How to iterate inside slash command?

Tags: java, slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-block-kit

I have a slash command that when called, prints a list of teams (which are stored in a List) with checkboxes next to them. I have no problem creating the checkboxes with a team name next to them, but only when the team name is hardcoded in. How can I iterate through the list and create an unknown amount of checkboxes?

```
app.command("/message", (req, ctx) -> {
  ctx.respond(res -> res
    .responseType("in_channel") // or "in_channnel"
    .blocks(asBlocks(
      section(section -> section.text(markdownText("Select channels to receive message")).accessory(
        checkboxes(checkboxes -> checkboxes
          .options(asOptions(
            option(option -> option.value("0").text(markdownText("some-team")))
            option(option -> option.value("1").text(markdownText("another-team")))
          ))
        )
      )),
      actions(actions -> actions
        .elements(asElements(
          button(b -> b.actionId("submit").text(plainText
            (pt -> pt.emoji(true).text("Submit"))).style("primary").value("submit"))
        ))
      )
    ))
  );
  return ctx.ack();
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your code for improving the readability?

Comment: @Reporter updated, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are familiar with working with block kit / block kit builder.

You can create the complete set of blocks as text 
and can then assign it using `blocksAsString(String)` method.

 https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/composing-messages :

> Building Blocks for Rich Message Layouts
>
> [Block Kit](https://api.slack.com/block-kit) is a UI framework for Slack apps that offers a balance
> of control and flexibility when building experiences in messages and
> other [surfaces](https://api.slack.com/surfaces).
>
> It may not be so easy to compose a large JSON data structure in Java
> code. So, we offer setter methods like blocksAsString(String) that
> accept a whole blocks part as a single string value. Such method is
> supposed to be used with loaded external file data or outcomes by
> template engines.

```
ChatPostMessageResponse response = slack.methods(token).chatPostMessage(req -> req
  .channel("C1234567")
  .blocksAsString("[{\"type\": \"divider\"}]")
);
```